# Conflict between local network and VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04).
My local wifi network is *192.168.1.0/24*, but
my VPN also *192.168.1.0/24* (point to point VPN).

**ifconfig**

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:7b:9d:98:da:f1  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:0 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:0 (0.0 B) Octets transmis:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:806 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:806 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1 
          Octets reçus:82090 (82.0 KB) Octets transmis:82090 (82.0 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Protocole Point-à-Point  
          inet adr:192.168.1.205  P-t-P:192.168.1.204  Masque:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1400  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:8 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:3 
          Octets reçus:185 (185.0 B) Octets transmis:237 (237.0 B)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:d4:0c:86:c6:76  
          inet adr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fd24:df6a:bd78:7b00:8109:a0c4:133a:892b/64 Scope:Global
          adr inet6: fd24:df6a:bd78:7b00:e534:8609:1c44:f40a/64 Scope:Global
          adr inet6: fe80::cdf7:32b8:de5b:ac15/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:6150 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4583 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:5540235 (5.5 MB) Octets transmis:658638 (658.6 KB)
```

**netstat -anr**

```
Table de routage IP du noyau
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic   MSS Fenêtre irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp2s0
80.13.172.131   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     192.168.1.204   255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.204   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
```

I want to redirect only requests from **192.168.1.39** to the VPN, How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the route to the ppp0 device:

```
192.168.1.0     192.168.1.204   255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 ppp0
```

with following command:

```
sudo route del -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 192.168.1.204
```

Then you need to add the route for 192.168.1.39

```
sudo route add -host 192.168.1.39 gw 192.168.1.204 dev ppp0
```